# Script Shell Extract String

Tags: shell, script

```
#! /bin/sh
lineversion ="/tmp/g-9.n.gggg1000.fr-worker1.V.2.tar.bz2"
```

My question: how can i extract

```
 g-9.n.gggg1000.fr-worker1.V.2
```

from

```
$lineversion
```

in another variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
newvar=`echo $lineversion | sed 's/\.tar\.bz2//' | sed 's/\/tmp\///'`
```

`sed` is unix's "search and replace" utility. In the above example, we are **s**earching for first ".tar.bz2" (and escaping the dots with a preceding backslash) and replacing it with nothing, and then taking that output and searching for "/tmp/" and replacing it with nothing similarly.

In general: `sed 's/search_for/replace_with/'`

Comment: You can save time and ressources by doing only one sed command ( and avoid double pipe) : newvar=`echo $lineversion | sed -e 's/\.tar\.bz2//' -e  sed 's/\/tmp\///'` . Plus, you missed the backquotes (`) around your command to set it into your variable.

Comment: Thanks - fixed! I gave up on memorizing sed's parameters because unlike grep, it's too different across Mac/Linux/BSD for me to keep straight (and I use all three).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the substring syntax to extract characters from fixed position :

```
echo ${lineversion:position:length}
echo ${lineversion:5:30}
```

Another method would be to cut a little bit of not needed characters :

```
echo ${lineversion} | cut -d '/' -f3 | sed 's/\.tar\.bz2$//g'
```

Comment: Nice answer, +1 from me! You have a typo in your initial example (no colon preceding the position)